# Computing 2's complement in Excel

Tags: excel, binary

How can I compute the **2s complement** of a binary number in Excel. Which Excel functions do I need?

For example, if I have the binary sequence `11101010`, the 2s complement can be obtained as,

1. Replace all 1's with 0's and 0's with 1's: `00010101`
2. add 1 to the result of step 1: `00010110`

An excel implementation of the above is what I need.

Answer (score 4):

Remember that Two's complement was invented as a way to to a subtraction in a computer to represent negative numbers, so this problem can be solved as a simple subtraction, so get the complement and then add one.

=DEC2BIN(255 - BIN2DEC(A1) + 1)

Where A1 is a cell with a binary number as text. If you want to use a bigger number then use the biggest number that can be represented by the number of bits that you want to use, here my example is for 8 bits, so (2^8)-1 = 255

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Scott Craner's answer is great since it implements that the OP had in mind using string manipulation. However, I feel a better idea would be to compute the 2's complement by Subtraction of Decimal numbers.

Use `BIN2DEC('Binary String')` or simply use the original decimal number that you may have converted to binary at some point.

Then if you want to compute the 8 bit 2's complement of your number you can simply subtract the number from `2^8`, using `POW(2, 8) - BIN2DEC('Binary String')`

Then convert it back to binary using `DEC2BIN()`

The definition of 2's complement with inverting bit patterns and adding 1 posted by the OP is just a consequence of this more fundamental [definition of 2's complement](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html). The author of this tutorial talks about this definition near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Two's complement, in it's basic form is a negative of it's decimal notation.

Much similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965536/) answer,

If A2 had the binary number, B2:

```
=RIGHT(DEC2BIN(-BIN2DEC(A2)),LEN(A2))
```

Caveats:

- Binary number cannot be more than 10 bits or characters with the first bit as the sign bit.

Answer (score 0):

This formula follows your steps:

```
=TEXT(DEC2BIN(BIN2DEC(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,2),0,1),2,0))+1),REPT("0",LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. But when i copy your part i get an error

Comment: @mrleo you may need to use `;` instead of `,` as your delimiters. Replace all the `,` with `;`.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, you may want the Two's Complement in the **same number of bits as the original number**.

Building off of [Guillermo Adrian Rodrguez Barr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62328202/4506399), we have a general formula for any number of bits:

```
=DEC2BIN(2^LEN(A1)-BIN2DEC(A1))
```

An 8-bit number will result in an 8-bit Two's Complement, and this will be for any number of bits. The `+1` is already included because `2^LEN(A1)` gets the unsigned bit range + 1.

If you do know exactly how many bits you want and want to use a constant, feel free to replace `LEN(A1)` with how many bits you want, such as `8`. In the op's example, this 8-bit formula would be equivalent to the general formula above:

```
=DEC2BIN(2^8-BIN2DEC(A1))
```